# GeckoFx 45 Get HTML of a new TAB/PopUp after clicked link (_blank)

Tags: tabs, popup, popupwindow, geckofx, createwindow

I work quite successfull with GeckoFX for some time now.
But now I got a problem getting the HTML of a site that was opened by clicking on a link with a target="_blank" attribute.

```
PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = Function() New MyPromptService()
Xpcom.ProfileDirectory = "C:\gecko-cache"
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox")
Dim form3 As New Form
Browser = New GeckoWebBrowser() 
Browser.Visible = True
form3.Controls.Add(Browser)
Browser.navigate("http://www.asd.com")
browser_wait_javascript(5)
Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").(0).Click()
browser_wait_javascript(5)
```

Now the Browser opens the content of this link in a new Window.
How to get the HTML code, click links in the new windows?
I like to have something like this:

```
dim new_browser_window = get_window(last_opened_window)
dim html = new_browser_window.document.getelementsbytagname("body").(0).outerHTML
```

Whats the best way to achieve this goal?

Thank you very much

```
 Public Sub browser_wait_javascript(ByVal maxTimeout As Integer)
    Dim maxTimeouttime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(maxTimeout)
    While DateTime.Now < maxTimeouttime
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0)
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    End While
    While Browser.IsBusy()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0)
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    End While
End Sub
```